# Determine if a certain regex is found in a text file (Java)

Tags: java, regex, string, text

I'm fairly new to Java, and I just started working with RegEx's and I was wondering which is the best way to check if, given a wall of text as input, a certain regular expression is found, and it's valid.
I'll make an example.

I've got this text file as input:

> Derpity64_1 64 3 6 1
>
> HerpDerp32 1 6 3 0 26
>
> HurrDurr16 2 5 7 7 78

Now, the part that is relevant to me is the HerpDerp32.
After I make sure that the text file contains that HerpDerp string, I want to make sure that the numbers after HerpDerp (32 in this case) are either 16, 32, or 64.

How do I go on? I'm sorry if I made any mistake/didn't explain too well.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for regexes here...

All you have to do is loop through the file (reading one line at a time).

Once you find a line that begins with your search term, simply inspect the characters after the term.

You can use [String.substring()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29) to inspect the characters after HerpDerp.

If you're going to be using java, you may as well get used to reading the API documentation.

Here's the [page with the String functions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).  You'll be using this **a lot**.

```
   http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html
```

Here's the [documentation for the FileReader class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html), which will also be helpful here.

Comment: I think I should've made an example closer to the actual thing. So, what I have got is not really a file. But I've designed a GUI with WindowBuilder in Eclipse, and I've got a JTextPane, and I do a textPane.getDocument() to actually get the text from it. Now I want to look for that particular string, that I know for sure it has to start with "STEAM" (It's a steam ID, if you have confidence), and I think I managed to get that regex to check it's a valid SteamID = "/^STEAM_0:(0|1):[0-9]{1}[0-9]{0,8}$/". What I have to do, is save in a variable the Steam ID, in case a vlid one is found. Sorry :D

Comment: It would make more sense to edit your question than to type all that here.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really have to use regex? Jahroy suggested something way faster

```
String[] data = { "Derpity64_1 64 3 6 1", "HerpDerp32 1 6 3 0 26",
        "HurrDurr16 2 5 7 7 78" };

for(String s:data){//iterate over all Strings in 'data' array
    if (s.startsWith("HerpDerp"))//check if tested string starts with HerpDerp
        //HerpDerp32 1 6 3 0 26
        //        ^^
        //0123456789
        //show only chars from 8 till 9 index
        System.out.println(s.substring(8,10));//(10 is excluded)
}
```

---

Edit:

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for because it is based on your original question, but try it using your data and your regex.

```
String[] data = { "Derpity64_1 64 3 6 1", "HerpDerp32 1 6 3 0 26",
    "HurrDurr16 2 5 7 7 78" };
Pattern p=Pattern.compile("^HerpDerp(\\d*)");
for (String s : data) {
    Matcher m=p.matcher(s);
    if(m.find()) 
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
        //group(1) will return content from first bracket in regex
}
```

Comment: I think I should've made an example closer to the actual thing. So, what I have got is not really a file. But I've designed a GUI with WindowBuilder in Eclipse, and I've got a JTextPane, and I do a textPane.getDocument() to actually get the text from it. Now I want to look for that particular string, that I know for sure it has to start with "STEAM" (It's a steam ID, if you have confidence), and I think I managed to get that regex to check it's a valid SteamID = "/^STEAM_0:(0|1):[0-9]{1}[0-9]{0,8}$/". What I have to do, is save in a variable the Steam ID, in case a vlid one is found. Sorry :D

Comment: @w0rm Check my edit. I don't know how your data looks like but hope this will help you find solution to of problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it gave me something to work on, I'm almost there :P